# How to change an <href> of an element in a <li> that's inside of a <div> using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, href

Please help to solve my issue.
I'm a novice in JS so I can't understand how to do this: I need to replace  parameters in a following string from

```
<a href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderation_split');" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>
```

of an existing page using GreaseMonkey script. Here is the part of the page HTML code itself:

```
<div class="profile-gallery-inner-wrapper">
        <ul class="profile-gallery js-photos-container">

            <!--Empty sections-->

            <li class="profile-gallery__item profile-gallery__item--no-image">
                <a href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderation_split');" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>
            </li>)

        </ul>

        <!--Gallery navigation-->

    </div>
```

Please help me with the JS code.

UPD. Solved the issue. It runs now. Somewhat not as expected, but it works.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Kismia
// @namespace   kismia.com
// @match       *://*kismia.com/*
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function ch_href () {

var a = document.querySelector('.profile-gallery__item__link');
if (a) {
a.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show\(false,     \'crop_split\'\)\;');
}
}
ch_href();

$(window).load (ch_href);
```

Comment: Show something you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<li>` element has the class `profile-gallery__item`, you can do this.

```
let anchor = document.getElementsByClassName("profile-gallery__item a")
anchor.setAttribute("href", "javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');")
```

Comment: Already tried exactly the same code. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: The variable `list` above only refers to the first list element with the class name `profile-gallery__item`. What exactly does not work? Have you inspected the page to see if the attribute has been set?

Comment: Yes, of course I've inspected the page. I do it every time I run the code. Nothing happens, the href value does not change.
There are two element on a page, that one I've mention above is the first. None of them changes regardless of the variants of JS code that I try to run.

Comment: What element do you want to modify the `href` of?

Comment: <!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<li class="profile-gallery__item profile-gallery__item--no-image">
                <a href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderation_split');" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>

Comment: The <a> element.

Comment: Yes, I edited the selector. Do you put the `<script>` tag below the `<body>` tag? You must ensure that the HTML loads before the script is run.

Comment: This script:
<code>// ==UserScript==
// name        Kismia
// namespace   kismia.com
// match       *://*kismia.com/*
// require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js
// version     1
// grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

<script>
function ch_href () {
    
var a = document.querySelector('a[href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderate_split');"]');
if (a) {
  a.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.that.new.link');
}
}

$(window).load (ch_href);
</script></code>
does not start at all... Exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Answer (score 0):

Just select anchor element and change attribute.

```
const anchor = document.querySelector('.profile-gallery__item__link');
anchor.setAttribute('href', 'javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');')
```

If you need to change attribute for multiple links you can select them all and do that in the loop like this:

```
const anchorAll = document.querySelectorAll('.profile-gallery__item__link');
for (let i = 0; i < anchorAll.lenght; i++) {
  anchorAll[i].setAttribute('href', "javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');")}
```

Comment: Yes, you code on jsfiddle is working fine, but on a real page it doesn't.
Nothing happens, the value of href is not changing.
What else can I try ?

Comment: Please check where you placed your code. Put it just before </body> closing tag. Also check console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping as close to the code you have at the moment, you could add an id to the `<a>` tag to identify it easier, for example

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderation_split');" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>

<script>
function changeLink() {
    var link = document.getElementById("myLink");
    link.setAttribute('href', "javascript:PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');");
}
</script>
```

The way it works is it uses the [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById%20getElementById) method to get the exact tag and store a reference to it in a variable called `link`, then you can perform any actions you wish on it, such as [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute%20setAttribute)

But I'd be tempted to take a different approach for this one

```
<a href="#" onClick="doAction()" class="profile-gallery__item__link"></a>

<script>
var whichAction = 1;

function doAction() {
    switch (whichAction) {
        case 1:
        PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_moderation_split');
        break;

        case 2:
        PhotoUploadDialog.show(false, 'crop_split');
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

function changeLink() {
    whichAction = 2;
}
</script>
```

What's going on here, is you are first storing a variable called `whichAction` and setting it to a value of 1. When you click on the link, a function called `doAction()` is called, which looks at the value of `whichAction` and performs whichever task is appropriate. Of course you could add as many cases in here as you wish if you need to have more choices in the future.

Now all your `changeLink()` function needs to do is change the value of your `whichAction` variable.

A further thing to note, is at the end of the `doAction()` function, you must have `return false;`, this tells the browser not to continue to follow the link in the `href=` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change anything in the HTML code, because that page in not mine, it's from an existing site on the Internet. I'm trying to change it using Stylish plugin.

Comment: Would probably be a good idea to mention that in the question, it is very relevant